# k-rotated array correctness

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

I wrote pseudo-code that finds the k'th number in a k rotate-sorted array. A
k rotate-sorted array is an array for which `A[k]<A[K+1]<...<A[1]<...<A[N]<...<A[K-1]`.

So in this array:

```
[3,4,5,6,7,1,2]
k=5
```

I'm having a hard time proving why my code is correct

```
find_k'th :
    start=A[1]
    end = A[n]
    while ( A[start]>A[end])
        start=A[floor(start+end)/2]
    return start;
```

Comment: Isn't the `k` simply the position where the ordering changes?

Comment: Yes, I thought about this but I didnt convinced myself enough, i guees this is the answer because in the range of the new [start - end] we now have unrotate-sorted array.